# Import from Parent Directory - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have the following project structure (simplified):

```
.
├── potusflavus
│   ├── potusflavus.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── dlcmanager.py
```

from `potusflavus.py`, I would like to import `dlcmanager.py`.  I thought that I had set up the structure correctly to simply do `import dlcmanager`, but when I run `potusflavus.py` this gives me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlcmanager'
```

I then tried `from . import dlcmanager`, but this gives me:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I would like understand how to import scripts in this way properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the parent directory to `sys.path`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from dlcmanager import ...
```